# Accessing Child control event from parent level wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, user-controls

I have a user control named myControl. I have rendered another user control named dialog inside myControl as `<uc:dialog x:Name="dialog">` .
I have a button named as myButton inside the dialog user control. I need to get the lostfocus event of myButton from the parent level .ie,myControl code behind.How can I get that? Which is the best way to do that?

```
    var myButton= dialog.FindName("myButton") as Button;

    if (myButton!= null)

    {
        myButton.LostFocus += myButton;
    }
```

I tried like this. But it doesn't work.Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define such an Event in your UserControl.
Then just register for this event.

```
public event EventHandler ButtonLostFocusEvent;
private void Button_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler testEvent = this.ButtonLostFocusEvent;

    // Check for no subscribers
    if (testEvent == null)
        return;

    testEvent(sender, e);
}
```